# Access a list outside of foreach statement

Tags: json, foreach

```
if (errors.Count > 0) {
 foreach(var error in errors) {
  List < JsonReportErrors > Results = new List < JsonReportErrors > ();
  new JsonReportErrors {
   ErrorKind = error.kind, ErrorPath = error.path
  };
 }

 List < ReturnJsonErrors > ReturnJson = new List < ReturnJsonErrors > ();
 new ReturnJsonErrors {
  Success = false, Errors = Results
 };

 return Json(ReturnJson, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I'm trying to access the Results list outside of the foreach in the `new ReturnJsonErrors { Success = false, Errors = Results  };` statement

but keep getting

```
Results does not exist in this context.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable exists only within the context it is declared in. In your case, it "lives" only inside the `foreach` loop. For it to be visible outside of it, you would have to declare it outside of it:

```
            List<JsonReportErrors> Results = new List<JsonReportErrors>();
            foreach (var error in errors)
            {
                new JsonReportErrors { ErrorKind = error.kind, ErrorPath = error.path };
            }
```

Also, you probably want to add the created `JsonReportErrors` object to this list, right? But that's a different issue...

Comment: Got it.  Now I understand.